# Make socket class available to entire app

Tags: flutter

I have the following class which I will use to display an alert regardless of which page the user is on within the app.

What is the best way to make this class accessible to all pages with in the app? Do I need to include it in every page and then call it in the init method of that page?

```
class SocketHelper{

  connect(){
SocketIO socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO("http://someurl", "/", query: "userId=123",socketStatusCallback: _socketStatus);
socketIO.init();
socketIO.subscribe("somealert", _onReceiveAlert);
socketIO.connect();
  }

  _onReceiveAlert(){
    // todo
  }

  _socketStatus(){
    // todo
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for some sort of state management solution. There are a lot of different options for state management on flutter including Provider, Bloc, Redux, MobX and others.

If you only need to do it for this one thing in the app, I would recommend Provider, given its easy to use and is a wrapper for InheritedWidget.

If you don't want to use a package for it, you could just use InheritedWidget as well. Just wrap your app in the InheritedWidget, and you should have access to the socket all the way down your widget tree.

But given that you have those two functions that update the socket state, I would really recommend Provider with ChangeNotifier.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Provider to pass it to other indépendant widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the singleton pattern for that. You can use dependency injections to that. They make it available everywhere in the app. You can use Provider but the problem with Provider is that you will need context to do that. If you think accessing context will be a problem then use [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package to do that.